# Pulling this custom readDataFile function into Eclipse to print .dat file data to console

Tags: java-io, datainputstream

**Goal:** Get the data from a .dat file and print it to the console in Eclipse

**Resources**: [fpfret.java](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ywzfyqq6bc91fi3/fpfret.java) and [PointF.java](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i8hbxayikr58mgq/PointF.java) and [dichromatic.dat](https://www.dropbox.com/s/099asev5eeuhya1/dichromatic.dat)

I have resolved all my issues and have just a few console errors, here's my code and my question is: How do I add the **[getCodeBase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getCodeBase%28%29)** method?

```
package frp3;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Vector;

public class FileRead {
  public static void main(String[] args) { //getDocumentBase
    System.out.println(readDataFile(getCodeBase() + "dichromatic.dat", 300, 750));
  }
  private static String getCodeBase() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
  }
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static PointF[] readDataFile(String filename, int min, int max) {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    Vector v = new Vector();
  try {
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream((new URL(filename)).openStream()));
    float f0, f1;
    while (true) {
          try {
            f0 = dis.readFloat();
            f1 = dis.readFloat();

            if (min < 0 || max < 0 || (f0 >= min && f0 <= max)) {
              v.addElement(new PointF(f0, f1));
            }
           }
           catch (EOFException eof) {
             break;
           }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    PointF[] array = new PointF[v.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
      array[i] = (PointF) v.elementAt(i);
    }

 return array; 
 }
}
```

Here's my console errors:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: nulldichromatic.dat
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
at frp3.FileRead.readDataFile(FileRead.java:27)
at frp3.FileRead.main(FileRead.java:12)
[Lfrp3.PointF;@29be513c
```

Here's my Project View in Eclipse:

[image]

Comment: can you provide a sample of that chromatic.dat? It will be easier to solve your problem

Comment: Actually that's the problem, I can share the .dat file, but I don't actually have the original txt file, so the data contained in the .dat file I have is my only hope of knowing anything about the graph I'm going to be drawing. I will attach the .dat file now..

Comment: Also I just completely re-organized this question, sorry for any confusion

Comment: Just for clarity, I didn't mention that I'm simply grabbing the readDataFile function from the entire Java Source code and running the function in Eclipse to perform its operations on .dat files. PointJ is simply another function that the readDataFile uses.

Comment: There are many libraries missing. Can you compile it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright. This is actually more complex then I thought at first pass. Basically, readDataFile expects the dichromatic.dat file to be a resource available on the Internet. Look at the following line from readDataFile:

```java
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream((new URL(filename)).openStream()));
```

Basically, whatever filename gets passed in, is used as a URL. For your use-case, where your file is hosted on your local filesystem, I recommend a few changes.

First, replace the above DataInputStream declaration line with:

```java
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename)));
```

Second, replace getCodeBase with:

```java
private static String getCodeBase() {
    return "";
}
```

I've simply replace null with an empty string. Since "dichromatic.dat" is in the root of your project, it should be sufficient to use an empty string, indicating project root, as the result for getCodeBase(), as the result of that function gets pre-pended to "dichromatic.dat" before being passed to readDataFile as `filename`.

If you put dichromatic.dat in a different place, just modify that empty string to be the "path" that leads to the file.

Hope this helps.

Forgot to mention -- be sure to update your imports list to include `import java.io.FileInputStream` -- although Eclipse should handle this gracefully for you.