# how to search keyword/specfic word from text file?

Tags: java, search

how can search specific word from file. like if we have have a text file and in filem, text is arranged line by line like...

The Apple is sweet.

the color of car is red.

the sky is blue..

Now user want to search car or red...
and input through text box so how can we search from file that match input text from file text and show reslut.
it may be possible that input word is more than 1 time in document then reslut also show how many times it appear in file.
 so how can we implement this....

Comment: First try and if you face any issue then paste code here.We will definetely help you

Comment: i have no sach idea how to impement that if have you any idea so plz share with me....

Comment: google it and you shall find enlightenment.

Comment: @user3271822, try *something*.  Try ANYTHING.  Write some code, see how far you get.  Having others do your work for you won't help beyond your immediate needs.

Comment: any hint how to do that....

Comment: @user3271822 [google](http://www.google.com)

Comment: @user3271822 take a look at my answer. With tath, you should have enough for a beginning

Comment: @user3271822 +1 would be appreciated. An accepted answer with -1 looks weird, don't you think?

Comment: @rapx Its my mistake how can i set this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an example of reading a file line by line here :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22074145/3315914

All you need is replace a few lines:

```
     public static ArrayList<String> searchInFile(String word) {


    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    FileReader fileReader = null;
    try {
        fileReader = new FileReader(new File("input.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        System.err.println("File input.txt not found!");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);
    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          if (line.contains(word)) {
              result.Add(word);
           }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error when processing the file!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Unexpected error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Never share code, if someone has not added any code.... but make the questioner think by providing some hint.

although, good to see your answer.. This will just check if the word is present or not. however if the person needs the exact occurrence location, use indexOf() instead of contains().

Comment: @anandc uhm... ok. I'll edit my answer, only for correctness. I'll take your advice about sharing code.

Comment: @anandc Decrypting the question, 

_Now user want to search car or red... and input through text box so how can we search from file that match input text from file text and show **reslut**. it may be possible that input word is more than 1 time in document then reslut also show how many times it appear in file. so how can we implement this_

Maybe he is talking about counting words?

Comment: we make people think, instead of spoon feeding :)

Comment: good point ! <br/>This is just a algorithm, required modifications can be made in order to serve the purpose.

Comment: @rapx it is usefull for me..

Comment: @Downvoter  care to comment?

Comment: @rapx using this can i search with in specfic line like in file i have 20 lines and i want to search from line 10 to 15 can this possible if yae so kindly help how can i do this....

Comment: @user3271822 Keep a counter variable, and do nothing while is< 10

Comment: @rapx one thing more that if a line contain  searchword like line number 10 cotain search word then in while loop i want to serach anoter word from line number 5 to 15 another word how can i do this??

Comment: @user3271822 I dont understand you

Comment: in this code we can search line by line so if a line number 10 contain searched word so in if condition i want to search another word from line number 5 to 15 how can do this?? @rpax

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple logic that one can apply

Load File
Iterate till the end
while iterating through every line, call lineString.indexOf("searchKeyword")
above line will let you know if the searchKeyword appears, if yes, you will get the starting location of the word in this string.

Comment: are you sure that's what he is asking?

Comment: Yes. this might be a search app where he might try to high light the search query, so in getting index will not harm instead of just getting true or false.

Comment: You're right. That would cover more scenarios