# how to print output in a text file

Tags: java, printwriter

I'm trying to read text from file, do some operation and output result in a different file but for some reason it only prints one line of the results.

```
    Scanner file = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("/.../file.txt"));
    PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("/.../output.txt"));

    int count = 0;

    while (file.hasNextLine()) 
    {
        String s = file.nextLine();
        count++; 
        try
        {
            if(s.contains("#AVFC")){
                p.printf("There are %d words on this line ", s.split("\\s").length-1);
                p.println(count);
                p.close();

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){ 
            ex.printStackTrace(); 
        } 



    }
    file.close();
```

this is output;

```
There are 4 words on this line 1
```

but the output should be:

```
There are 4 words on this line 1

There are 10 words on this line 13

There are 8 words on this line 16
```

Comment: Here you have a working example of reading and writing to files:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/22074145/3315914

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you close `p` in `while` loop?

```
Scanner file = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("/.../file.txt"));
PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("/.../output.txt"));

int count = 0;

while (file.hasNextLine()) 
{
    String s = file.nextLine();
    count++; 
    try
    {
        if(s.contains("#AVFC")){
            p.printf("There are %d words on this line ", s.split("\\s").length-1);
            p.println(count);

        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){ 
        ex.printStackTrace(); 
    } 



}

p.close();
file.close();
```

in your code `PrintWriter` closed on first match found in file and other matches will not write in output file because you closed file writer before.

Comment: my goodness such a silly mistake lol its been a long day thank u sir

Answer (score 0):

Do not close your `PrintWriter` within the loop. (you still need it.) Just close it after the loop.

```
 while(file.hasNextLine())
 { 
    // your code goes here...
 }
 p.close();
 file.close();
```