# Java creating a file on mac?

Tags: java

I have made a plugin for this mine craft server and its a diary, you write stuff down on a .txt and you can read it in game. I set it up so you can change the directory in game and the creating files and reading them works fine on windows until I found out the sever owner is on a mac, is it possible to create file and read them the same as windows to mac?

Comment: Yes. Here you have an example of reading and writing : http://stackoverflow.com/a/22074145/3315914

Comment: Did you try it and see?

Comment: If you wrote a good code the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

Java is a highly portable language. Your code will work as long as you don't place any Windows-specific assumptions in your code. For example, this is bad:

```
new File("C:\\My\\Directory\\File.txt");
```

This is better...

```
new File("/My/Directory/File.txt");
```

Better still...

```
new File(File.separator + "My" + File.separator + "Directory" + File.separator + "File.txt");
```

Best!

```
File file = new File(File.separator);
file = new File(file, "My");
file = new File(file, "Documents");
file = new File(file, "File.txt");
```

[Read the JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) for more info on how to accomplish your goals in a system-independent way.